# Reading And Writing to MYSQL in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8czu.png)I'm able to connect to MYSQL while running my Pyspark Code Locally in juypter notebook, but the same code I am getting Communication error in AWS Glue while running the code. I have added MySQL jar in jar files required while creating the job in AWS Glue.

## Reading from MYSQL

dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/read").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "student").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()

## Writing to MYSQL

df = sc.parallelize([[25, 'Prem'],

```
                  [20, 'Kate'],

                 [20, 'Kate'],

                  [40, 'Cheng']]).toDF(["Depy_id","Dept_name"])
```

df.write.format('jdbc').options(

```
  url='jdbc:mysql://localhost/test',

  driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',

  dbtable='dept',

  user='root',

  password='root').mode('overwrite').save()
```

Comment: Can you test the connection under connections  and see if it is successful?

Comment: I didn't get it. what do you mean by  test the connection under connections.

Comment: AWS Glue Console -> Databases -> Connections -> Select the connection used created for ETL Job -> Click Test connection .You can test a connection by following this navigation.

Comment: my job is created by custom written pyspark script.I  didn't set up any connection in AWS.

Comment: Can you create one, add it to your Glue job and retry running the job.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have to provide a valid database URL, not a localhost.  I believe your jupyter notebook was run locally on a laptop, in the same local environment where your mysql is running as well.

AWS Glue runs within an AWS environment, and behind the scene it would launch number of EC2 instances depending upon the DPU configuration.  If your URL is configured as LOCALHOST, then the EC2 instance where the pyspark code is running, would look for a mysql database on the same node.

Please make sure you have a valid public IP for the mysql database, and try to setup a connection in the AWS Glue as suggested by bdcloud, and retry again.  If you dont want to create a connection, you can hard code the connection parameters in the code and try again.  If you cannot get a public IP for the installed mysql database, maybe you can try setup an RDS Mysql on AWS, and use it for testing.

### Sample code snippet:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=url, user=uname, password=pwd, database=dbase)
cur = conn.cursor()

insertQry = "INSERT INTO emp (id, emp_name, dept, designation, address1, city, state, active_start_date, is_active) SELECT (SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM atlas.emp) id, tmp.emp_name, tmp.dept, tmp.designation, tmp.address1, tmp.city, tmp.state, tmp.active_start_date, tmp.is_active from EMP_STG tmp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dept=tmp.dept, designation=tmp.designation, address1=tmp.address1, city=tmp.city, state=tmp.state, active_start_date=tmp.active_start_date, is_active =tmp.is_active ;"

n = cur.execute(insertQry)
print (" CURSOR status :", n)
```

Please refer to the AWS Glue connections section:
[image]